# How to store content of variable (and not the macro) in another variable?

Tags: input, variable

When implementing \input{file} to feed content that are stored into variables for later use the curious problem occurs that the \def\variable that is being used is altered along with the content of \input file, rendering the operation null and void.

An MWE explains better:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[8pt,a4paper]{article} %
\begin{document}
\input{root.tex} 
\test \\
\testa \\
\testb \\
\end{document}
```

root.tex

```
\def\test{letter root}
\input{letters/sub_1.tex} \def\testa{\test}
\input{letters/sub_2.tex} \def\testb{\test}
```

sub_1.tex:

```
\def\test{sub 1}
```

sub_2.tex:

```
\def\test{sub 2}
```

This renders as

```
letter_root
letter_root
letter_root
```

...instead of

```
sub_1
sub_2
letter_root
```

How to store these variables right?

Comment: Assuming the macro names are fixed in the input files, you can copy/rename them using \let.  `\let\originaltest=\test\input{sub1}\let\newtest=\test` etc.

Comment: Or `{\input{sub1}\global\let\newtest=\test}` redefines \test locally only.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!